# Adding a Menu to the app menu in AppKit using NSMenu

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I'm trying to add a menu to the app menu through Appkit by using the NSMenu Class. But I'm not sure how to call it so far I've tried:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var menu: NSMenu!




    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view.
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 512),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        class myMenu: NSMenu {
            init(aTitle: "HelloWorld")
        }
    }
```

But this only gives me "Expected parameter type following ':'" and "'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'NSMenu'".

Comment: You need to add your menu to `NSApplication.shared.mainMenu`. See answers to this question for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781974/how-to-add-nsmenu-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I use separate functions for buildWnd and buildMenu, but this should work using your technique.  Create a new file in your swift project called main.swift and delete the pre-existing AppDelegate.  Copy/paste this code into the main.swift file.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
   // var menu: NSMenu!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
       // let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view.
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 512),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
     //   window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        let mainMenu = NSMenu()
        NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
       // **** App menu **** //
        let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
        let appMenu = NSMenu()
        appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
        appMenu.addItem(withTitle:"Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")

    }
}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** Main **** //
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.delegate = appDelegate
//application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. In my appDelegate's `didFinishLaunch`, I wrote:

```
 if let menuBar = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu,
   let appMenu = menuBar.items.first?.submenu {
  let newItem = NSMenuItem(
                  title: "My Thing…", 
                  action: #selector(myThing),
                  keyEquivalent: "U")
  appMenu.insertItem(updateItem, at: 1)
}
```

and at the end of the file

```
extension AppDelegate {
  @objc func myThing() {
    // do it
  }
}
```