# How to forward an NSEvent * to a WebView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, nsview

I have a `WebView` that is embedded inside the UI of an audio plugin. The plugin runs as a dynamic library within a range of hosts on OS X that support the plugin format.

In most hosts the `WebView` works as normal, in that if I have a HTML text input field loaded, and it has focus it accepts all text entry as normal.

However, in one specific host key combinations involving the Apple "cmd" key get "rejected" by the text input field and forwarded back to the containing `WebView`. I can confirm this if I use a subclass of `WebView` and override `NSView keyDown:` as follows:

```
@interface MyWebView : WebView
{
}
@end

@implementation MyWebView

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"keyDown [%@]", [event characters]);
}

@end
```

In most hosts `keyDown:` never gets called when text is entered in a focused text input field. In my problematic host it gets called for any key combinations involving the "cmd" key, resulting in the following call stack:

```
#0  0x00000001255fdf45 in ::-[MyWebView keyDown:](NSEvent *) at /Users/../juce_mac_WebBrowserComponent.mm:181
#1  0x00007fffa554bb79 in forwardMethod ()
#2  0x00007fffafa5bb7a in -[WebFrameView keyDown:] ()
#3  0x00007fffa554bb79 in forwardMethod ()
#4  0x00007fffa554bb79 in forwardMethod ()
#5  0x00007fffa554bb79 in forwardMethod ()
#6  0x00007fffa56e97d6 in -[NSControl keyDown:] ()
#7  0x00007fffafa48835 in -[WebHTMLView keyDown:] ()
#8  0x00007fffa5cc333c in -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] ()
#9  0x00007fffa5cc1f7a in -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] ()
#10 0x00007fffa5b47518 in -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] ()
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent the event from being rejected by the input field, or better understand why it's only getting passed back to the containing view for certain plugin hosts.

In the worst case, is it possible to somehow force the `NSEvent` to be forwarded back to the HTML input field?

**UPDATE**

OK, I can "fix" this in a hacky way by checking the event keyCode in my keyDown method, and for the events I care about (cut/copy/paste), use `NSApplication sendAction:to:from:` to have the events processed accordingly. Something like this:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    SEL selector = nil;

    switch ([event keyCode])
    {
        case 7:
            selector = @selector(cut:);
            break;
        case 8:
            selector = @selector(copy:);
            break;
        case 9:
            selector = @selector(paste:);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (selector != nil)
    {
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:selector to:nil from:self];
    }
}
```

I would much prefer a more generic solution though...

Comment: What do you mean by "rejected by the WebView"? What should happen with these key combination events and what is actually happening? Why would "forc[ing] the NSEvent to be forwarded back to the WebView" help? Your experiment shows the event is reaching the WebView. Your `-keyDown:` method is being invoked.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the question, which hopefully clarifies this. Basically, what I mean is that if I type in a text input field loaded in the WebView, cmd- combinations get passed back to the WebView rather than being consumed by the input field. All other keys work and the problem only occurs when my plugin is loaded in one specific host. Very strange.

Comment: Do the hosts where your plugin works have an Edit menu with the standard items with the standard keyboard shortcuts? Does the host where things don't work lack such a menu/items?

Comment: OK, just checked. And for hosts that work, if I type cmd-p, the host's Edit menu is highlighted briefly and then the clipboard contents get pasted into the input field. For the host that doesn't work the host's Edit menu doesn't highlight and my keyDown gets called. So it seems like maybe the issue is more to do with the keypress not reaching the host (which owns the window containing the WebView) ?

Comment: That should be cmd-v not cmd-p...

Comment: In the broken host, does the Paste menu item have Command-V as its shortcut? When focus is on your text field, if you open the Edit menu, is Paste enabled? If it's enabled, does selecting it with the mouse work as it should? If it's disabled or doesn't work, the host may have it connected to an incorrect target rather than the responder chain. You can try overriding `-performKeyEquivalent:` in your WebView to translate the standard key combinations to edit actions.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048241/obj-c-why-is-my-nstextfield-subclass-having-an-effect-on-objects-i-havent-assi) for an exploration of some of the subtleties with the `-performKeyEquivalent:` approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142606/discussion-between-jamie-bullock-and-ken-thomases).